# How to colorize a part of code in a GitHub repository?

Tags: github

How to make code selected on GitHub? 
For [example](https://github.com/FilledStacks/flutter-tutorials/blob/d92ea35b1a23660d224bf420fece39e785476956/tik_tok_ui/lib/widgets/actions_toolbar.dart#L27-L41), there is a part of the code selected with background color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this URL:

```
https://github.com/FilledStacks/flutter-tutorials/blob/d92ea35b1a23660d224bf420fece39e785476956/tik_tok_ui/lib/widgets/actions_toolbar.dart#L27-L41
```

The `#L27-L41` is your answer. You can modify this manually to select a large range of lines.

Alternatively, you can click the first line you'd like to highlight, hold down Shift, then click the end of the range of lines you'd like to highlight. The URL in your web browser will be updated to reflect this.